# does "javascript:" do something in an event attribute?

Tags: javascript, html

In the following html piece, does `javascript:` do something?

```
<input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" value="" 
 onkeydown="if(event.keyCode == 13){
                  if(IsValidBrowser()==true){
                          javascript:Continue();
                        //^^^^^^^^^^^
                  } else {
                     alert('Please use Safari, Google Chrome, or MS 
                     Internet Explorer version 7.0 or higher.');
                  }
           }"
 />
```

I thought that `javascript:` was only to be used in the href property of a `<a>` tag, but I run into this. 
Thanks.

Comment: That's a goto label.  It shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the point here is `javascript: prefix` has a bit confusing use cases. there are 2 different use for that:

1- the first and the most important use of `javascript: prefix` is when you want to put a piece of your javascript code in an anchor `href` attribute, it is extremely important to add the `javascript: prefix`, like:

```
<a href="javascript:alert('my href code');">My Link</a>
```

in this use `javascript: prefix` is not optional and you can not change the label `javascript`.

2- the other use is when you use `javascript: prefix` in your JavaScript code. it is most likely to get confused about the role it plays. actually in the javascript code developers can use prefixes to set a label on their code, which has no effect.

if so, why is that there?

the answer would be just to put a label on a piece of code to make it more descriptive or for any other reason the coder would probably have. based on this use:

```
javascript:Continue();
```

could be like this:

```
myloopcontinue:Continue();
```

which `myloopcontinue:` has no actual effect.

my favorite feature that these labels give us is when we use them in our loops, with `continue` and `break` javascript keywords, like this:

```
myloop:for(;;) {
    if(window.myvar===undefined){
        window.myvar = "Hello myloop";
        alert('myloop first iterate');
        continue myloop;
    }
    alert('myloop second and last iterate');
    break myloop;
}
```

for more infrmation about these kinds of label check this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FStatements%2Flabel).